# How can i pass the value of multiple input box to another single input or textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```html
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
<input type='date' name='date' id='date'>
<textarea name='text' id='text'></textarea>
```

Expected Output (in textarea box): My "name" and date is "date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is tagged [jquery] (regardless of need for this sample), so here you are

```js
$("input").on("input", () => {
  $("#text").text(`My name is "${$("#name").val().trim()}" and the date is "${$("#date").val().trim()}".`);
}).trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'><br/>
<input type='date' name='date' id='date'><br/>
<textarea cols=60 name='text' id='text'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var date = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
go();
function go(){
  textarea.innerHTML="My "+input.value+" and date is "+date.value;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' oninput="go()" value="Spectric">
<input type='date' name='date' id='date' oninput="go()" value="2021-01-25">
<textarea name='text' id='text'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with vanila java script just apply change event on both of the first input and append the value of it to the value of textarea

this is html code

```
<script src="./index.js" defer></script>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
<input type='date' name='date' id='date'>
<textarea name='text' id='text'></textarea>
```

this is js code

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('text')
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keydown' , (e) => {
    textArea.value = e.target.value
})
document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('change' , (e) => {
    console.log(textArea.value + e.target.value);
    textArea.value = textArea.value + "" +e.target.value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateTextArea() {
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  document.getElementById("text").value = "My name is " + name + " and the date is " + date;
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' oninput="updateTextArea()"><br>
<input type='date' name='date' id='date' oninput="updateTextArea()"><br>
<textarea name='text' id='text'></textarea>
```